# VBA copy a found value

Tags: excel, vba

I am fairly new to VBA . I have been trying to get this code working to no avail, basically I have a search to find a value (That part is working) and I want to copy that value and the row where this value is located into another sheet on the next empty row and date stamp it. Any help will be appreciated. Many Thanks.

This a sample of the table:
[Sample Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtBv4.jpg)

This is the code I have half working:

```
Sub FindingValues()
    Dim val As String
    Dim result As String
    Dim firstAddress As String
    Dim c As Range


    val = InputBox("Enter ID")
    Set c = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E:E").Find(val, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                               MatchCase:=False)


    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = c.Address
'        Application.Goto c
        Copy.Sheets(Sheet2).c

            Set c = Cells.FindNext(c)
        Else
         If c Is Nothing Then

         MsgBox "Could Not Find " & Res

         End If


        End If
```

Comment: Do you expect multiple matches?

Comment: Nope just one match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do it...

```
Sub FindingValues()
Dim val As String, result As String, firstAddress As String, entryROW As Long
Dim c As Range

'PGCodeRider making assumption to inser in column A
Dim columnNumberToPasteData As Long
columnNumberToPasteData = 1

'assumes Sheet2 is where data should be copied
Dim WS2 As Worksheet
Set WS2 = Sheets("Sheet2")


val = InputBox("Enter ID")

'probably want something like this so that if user wants to cancel
If val = "" Then Exit Sub


Set c = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E:E").Find(val, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                           MatchCase:=False)

If Not c Is Nothing Then

    entryROW = WS2.Cells(Rows.Count, columnNumberToPasteData).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    WS2.Rows(entryROW).Value = c.Worksheet.Rows(c.Row).Value
    WS2.Cells(entryROW, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Value = VBA.Now

'    With WS2.Cells(entryROW, columnNumberToPasteData)
'        .Offset(0, 0).Value = c.Value
'        .Offset(0, 1).Value = c.Row
'        .Offset(0, 2).Value = Now()
'    End With
'
Else

    If c Is Nothing Then MsgBox "Could Not Find " & val

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help PGCodeRider is working but, I would like to copy the entire row of information I don't really need the row number. how do you go about doing that?

Comment: @Charls how would you copy the whole row and also have the timestamp?

Comment: You are correct I would like to copy the row of values (depName, lastName, ect)  and also time stamp it.

Comment: Thanks for your help PGCodeRider greatly appreciated